# Loading sympy in Enthought Canopy causes kernel to die

Tags: enthought, sympy

I just installed Enthought Canopy and it's great but I'm having trouble using simpy in the IPython notebook implementation.

Creating a new notebook in Canopy and then using either

```
%load_ext sympyprinting
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *
```

or just

```
import sympy
```

causes the kernel to die, with the message, "The kernel has died, would you like to restart it? If you do not restart the kernel, you will be able to save the notebook, but running code will not work until the notebook is reopened."

Ordinarily I would start the html notebook with "ipython notebook --sympy" or some such, but I don't know how to pass the "--[...]" argument while using Canopy. Is this possible, or is there another technique to using Sympy this way? I've already installed Sympy via Canopy's GUI package manager.

PS I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04, with no sort of python installed except the Canopy suite, or anything that Ubuntu might come with by default.

Comment: It might be more productive to ask about / report a bug at the Enthought Canopy team.

Comment: What version of SymPy is it?

Comment: I have SymPy 0.7.2, the version installable through the Canopy packages GUI. Also, I thought the Canopy website suggested questions be posted here and that this is where the team looks for them, but maybe I read that wrong. They were in fact very helpful earlier for me with a bug report I submitted through the program when it crashed more severely.

Comment: I also get this problem - Sympy 0.7.2, Canopy 1.1.1.1452, Debian Squeeze

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but as of SymPy 0.7.2, the IPython printing extension is shipped as part of SymPy.  So you should instead do

```
%load_ext sympy.interactive.ipythonprinting
```

You can also use the `init_printing()` function. If you also want to automatically import everything and define common symbol names like `x`, `y`, and `z`, use `init_session()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info but that doesn't seem to help with Canopy